# Creating photo albums with Wordpress on an existing site

Tags: upload, wordpress, image-gallery

I'm looking for a solution to a particular query. I've got a website that I have made for a client and I coded my own image uploader/thumbnail creator but it's not handling what he wants very well.

So basically I'm looking for alternatives, and someone suggested using Wordpress and one its plugins to help upload albums. This seems straight forward after a bit of reading. But can I integrate it with my current set up:

- A user logs into their account on the site (I've set up user accounts in a DB),
- They see which albums are associated with this account.
- They open the album and the images appear.

So I guess what I'm asking is, how configurable is wordpress to fit in with my current set up. I need to be able to only display albums related to the logged in user to them.

Tbh if my current way worked consistently (the upload/thumbnail creation is all done in PHP), I would prefer to use that, but this has gone on for a while and I just want to give him a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use this wordpress plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: I'm currently working on a Wordpress site with NextGen as my gallery backend; I needed to add video support so I've been digging through the code. It's code is written nicely and should be easey to make any modifications you need. To integrate with an existing website, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website .

Comment: i don't really want to start modifying the code too much. with these gallery plugins i want to give my client a nice interface for uploading images into albums and then make these available to particular users

Comment: nextgen-gallery is by far the best choice for integrating a gallery into wordpress - look no further.